# Site loads very slowly (4-5 minute load time)

Tags: redirect, htaccess, apache

I'm hosting a WP site on a VPN so I'm doing all of the server management. A while back, I simply renamed my WP folder so that it would be inaccessible. Now I need it to be accessible again and so I renamed it to what it was before. For some reason the site is now extremely slow. As you can see in this screenshot, the server spends about 5 minutes doing who knows what before returning anything.

[image]

Here is the .htaccess file within my /blog/ directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have tried to disable the plugins by renaming the `/plugins/` directory to `/plugins.hold/` with no success. Still, though. Any idea why the theme could be causing this issue? It would be nice to have the theme working again!

I have tried to look at the apache error logs and nothing suspect seems to show up at the warning level. I also looked at my .htaccess files and didn't find anything out of the ordinary (as far as I know, the WP files have not been modified at all). The site does use HTTPS so I wonder if it has to do with changes that may have been made while the WP site was not being used. I'm thinking this is more of an Apache config problem, but any insight as to how I can debug this would be much appreciated. If you need me to post more info I will happily do so.

**UPDATE 1**

It seems to be a problem with my current theme, Salient. Once I switched to another theme, the site appears to load normally.

Comment: Have you tried testing how long it takes to load an HTML file and basic PHP file

Comment: @JohnWheal , for sure. if I load one of the other files in the /blog/ directory such as `license.txt` or `readme.html`, or even a test PHP file, it loads instantly. So it's something about that folder and the WP files within it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the amount of processes that your site has to carry out before being able to deliver the content, in this particular case to generate the HTML code and be able to dispatch it.

It is a fairly common problem among predesigned plugins and templates, even if they are paid they have this problem ... together the problems that many drag when using editors as "visual composer"

The immediate solution is to install some plugin for cache and to merge CSS and JS files

[merge-minify-refresh](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/merge-minify-refresh/)

[wp-super-cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)

In the long run it would be convenient to replace the template

Answer (score 0):

This may be a stretch but I've had a similar problem in the past, for me it was connected to caching. I would of just posted this as a comment but I don't have the rep yet.

Make sure if you had/have any old cache, it has been purged. Also depending on your cache plugin it may of inserted code that has been left behind or reinserted a double snippet into your template files.

Hope that helps!